# Dynamically coupling XAML with code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

**A little background information**

I am learning Xamarin.Forms and am currently struggling a bit with dynamically coupling my `ContentPage`'s XAML with my code-behind. Obviously, I am at the mercy of my complete unawareness of how Xamarin.Form's should be written, so I hope you can bare with my slight confusion.

I am developing a mobile application for Android and am using the [BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) to put the navigation bar at the bottom, which is working well. Currently, I am using the example project for my learning.

**The actual problem**

I have created a series of `ContentPage`'s which I would like to dynamically couple upon instantiating each new page. My `ContentPage`'s have corresponding code-behind, which I have left untouched; e.g., I have a `ContentPage` named `HomePage`, which have this code-behind:

```
namespace BottomBarXFExample
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
 }
```

and this corresponding XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BottomBarXFExample.HomePage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The way I go about creating pages is as follows.

```
 string[] tabTitles = { "Me", "Trends", "Home", "Plan", "About" };

        ContentPage[] pages = new ContentPage[tabTitles.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < tabTitles.Length; ++i)
        {
            ContentPage page = createPage(tabTitles[i]);
            bottomBarPage.Children.Add(page);
        }
```

The `createPage` method:

```
private ContentPage createPage(String title)
    {

        FileImageSource icon = setIcon(title);

        ContentPage page = new ContentPage()
        {
            Title = title,
            Icon = icon,
        };

        // should something happen here with the XAML?
        return page;
    }
```

And the `setIcon` method:

```
private FileImageSource setIcon(String title)
    {
        FileImageSource icon = (FileImageSource)FileImageSource.FromFile(
            string.Format(
                "ic_" + title.ToLowerInvariant() + ".png",
                title.ToLowerInvariant()
                ));

        return icon;
    }
```

Using this approach I am successful in creating the bottom navigation bar. However, navigating to each page using the navigation bar, the view is "obviously" empty, because I am not linking the `ContentPage` to its corresponding XAML. Can this be done in code?

If I opt for instantiating each `ContentPage` the "right" way:

```
HomePage homePage = new HomePage()
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = homeIcon
        };
```

And then add them to the navigation bar like so:

```
bottomBarPage.Children.Add(homePage)
```

I do obtain coupling between XAML and code-behind. However, I find it rather tedious, and probably also unnecessary, to do it this way.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Xaml pages and code behind classes are tightly coupled in xaml file with `x:Class` definition. Xaml pages cannot be inherited, but ContentPage classes can but I don't see that resolving your issues. If you're looking after having only one xaml page then you'd have to create the rendering logic in code behind, e.g.

```
public HomePage(string title)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    switch(title)
    {
       // set Binding Context to your VM
       ... BindingContext = titleBasedVM;
    }
}
```

Your VM can then contain page specific data. This concept uses [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm), which is highly recommended when using Xamarin Forms.

Also take a look at [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/introduction) for rendering generic page sections.

You shouldn't try to generate xaml dynamically as it's not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, JanneP. I will look into revising my whole approach - it does seem this is where I am going wrong.